# How To fix unassigned shards on ELK

Tags: sharding, elk

i have an ELK cluster with 3 nodes:
node1: *hims
node2: mw
node3: cm
my cluster is in yellow status and i have 10 shards not assigned:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elastic",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 3,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
  "active_primary_shards" : 829,
  "active_shards" : 829,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 10,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 98.80810488676997
}
```

when i check for one of the unassigned shard i got this explanation:

```
{
  "index" : ".siem-signals-default-000002",
  "shard" : 0,
  "primary" : true,
  "current_state" : "started",
  "current_node" : {
    "id" : "ID000000node1",
    "name" : "Node1",
    "transport_address" : "IP____Node1:9300",
    "attributes" : {
      "xpack.installed" : "true",
      "transform.node" : "false"
    },
    "weight_ranking" : 3
  },
  "can_remain_on_current_node" : "yes",
  "can_rebalance_cluster" : "no",
  "can_rebalance_cluster_decisions" : [
    {
      "decider" : "rebalance_only_when_active",
      "decision" : "NO",
      "explanation" : "rebalancing is not allowed until all replicas in the cluster are active"
    },
    {
      "decider" : "cluster_rebalance",
      "decision" : "NO",
      "explanation" : "the cluster has unassigned shards and cluster setting [cluster.routing.allocation.allow_rebalance] is set to [indices_all_active]"
    }
  ],
  "can_rebalance_to_other_node" : "no",
  "rebalance_explanation" : "rebalancing is not allowed",
  "node_allocation_decisions" : [
    {
      "node_id" : "ID000000node2",
      "node_name" : "node2",
      "transport_address" : "IP_____node2:9300",
      "node_attributes" : {
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "transform.node" : "false"
      },
      "node_decision" : "no",
      "weight_ranking" : 1,
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "data_tier",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "index has a preference for tiers [data_content] and node does not meet the required [data_content] tier"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "node_id" : "ID000000Node3",
      "node_name" : "node3",
      "transport_address" : "IP_____node3:9300",
      "node_attributes" : {
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "transform.node" : "false"
      },
      "node_decision" : "no",
      "weight_ranking" : 2,
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "disk_threshold",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "the node is above the low watermark cluster setting [cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low=85%], using more disk space than the maximum allowed [85.0%], actual free: [10.484763703454583%]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "data_tier",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "index has a preference for tiers [data_content] and node does not meet the required [data_content] tier"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

All the 10 unassigned shards have the same issue and error ...

I tried to run the reroute command but nothing happened